# Не получается вытащить CSS селектор , при помощи Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Обучаюсь по книге, заранее прошу прощения за кривое объяснения проблемы.

Задание следующее - при помощи Selenium'a зайти в почту gmail.com.
Код написанный в книге устарел, поэтому самостоятельно его видоизменял, в рабочий вид, на сайт переходит, почту вбивает, а с вводом пароля возникли проблемы. Код ниже:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://gmail.com')
emailElem = browser.find_element_by_id('identifierId')
emailElem.send_keys('a@gmail.com')
em = browser.find_element_by_class_name('CwaK9')
em.click()


passwordElem = browser.find_element_by_class_name('whsOnd zHQkBf')
passwordElem.send_keys('12345')
passwordElem.submit()
```

Насколько я понимаю под каждого генерируется свой уникальный класс-нейм, **но хочу понять принцип, что надо указать для пароля, чтобы программа заработала**, попробовал следующие методы:

```
browser.find_element_by_class_name
browser.find_element_by_id
browser.find_element_by_link_text
```

С соответствующими значениями, но пароль он не вбивает, в консоле пишет:

```
  passwordElem = browser.find_element_by_class_name('whsOnd zHQkBf')
  File "C:\Users\Анна\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 564, in find_element_by_class_name
    return self.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value=name)
  File "C:\Users\Анна\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 978, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Users\Анна\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Анна\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: .whsOnd zHQkBf
```

Comment: ну а вы уверены, что такой класс у input с паролем?

Comment: Если бы был уверен, не задал бы сюда вопрос :) Хочу понять, какой класс использовать, возможно проблема в том, что есть функция скрытого пароля и та, что показывает ввод, как в случае с емейлом. Но это лишь предположение, опять же, если я прав хочу понять, как в этом случае найти нужный класс

Comment: попробуйте искать элемент через `cssSelector("input[type=password]")`